# Write in Log file c#

Tags: c#, xml, logfile

I have a code in which I read from a XML file a path in which I have to save my results, and in case there is an error in the program and it stops, write down the error.

My program has this structure:

```
namespace RiskFactorListUpdater
{
    public static class Program
    {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                //get the data
                filename=.....;
                // blah blah blah


                // more code

              }catch(Exception e)
               {
                //write in log file
             }
```

The problem comes when I try to read the path which is filename.  I can't read it in the catch "section". I am a newbie in c#. Is there an easy way for doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you update your question with clearer details? I have a hard time understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: just declare the filename outside of the `try {...} block`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 you can use below method in proper formating way.
    public static class Program
        {
            public static string filename {get;set} 

            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                    filename="";
                    try
                    {      
                      filename=.....;
                    }
                   catch(Exception e)
                   {
                      //write in log file
                   }
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 5):

Declare anything you want to use in the `catch` block before the `try` block.

```
public static class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filename;
        try
        {
            //get the data
            filename=.....;
            // blah blah blah


            // more code

          }catch(Exception e)
           {
            //write in log file
         }
```